# Quasi-isometric embedding and ends of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $f:X\longrightarrow Y $ is an (L-A)-quasi isometry of proper geodesic metric spaces, that is
$$ \frac{1}{L}d_X(x,y)-A\leq d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leq Ld_X(x,y)+A,$$
for every $x,y\in X$.

Let $C_R$ be a connected component of $X\setminus B(R,x)$, where $B(R,x)$ is the closed ball of radius $R$ and center an arbitrary point $x\in X$.

Suppose, without loss of generality that $N_{A+1}(C_R)\subseteq C_r$, where $C_r$ is a connected component of $X\setminus B(r,x)$ for some $r\leq R$ and  $N_{A+1}(C)$ is the $A+1$-neighborhood of $C$.

Why is  $N_{A+1}(f(C_R))$ contained in $Y\setminus f(B_r)$?

My question arises from one step of the proof of Proposition 6.6 of the following book https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/kapovich_drutu.pdf.